# How to disable the Google Maps mobile site ad inside of an iOS UIWebView?

Tags: ios, iphone, google-maps, uiwebview

The ad shows up sometimes when loading the Google Maps mobile page inside of a UIWebView. Is there a way to never have it show up or a work around?

[image]

Comment: I doubt there is a way to do this if you really want to use the mobile site in a `UIWebView`. You don't really have a lot of control over the content being displayed, and Google isn't going to want you bypassing their ads anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Google APIs terms of services: https://developers.google.com/maps/terms

*c) Opting Out of Ads. You may at any time opt out of advertising in the places results and the maps images by either:

(i) contacting the Google Maps API for Business sales team to obtain a Google enterprise license; or

(ii) terminating your use of the Service.*

Comment: Gotta love option (ii) !